# Why do my .bat always loses its variable after the lengthy commands

Tags: file, variables, batch-file

Here is my .bat suffering from the adversity. Lets name it `b.bat`.

```
set loopnum=%1
set url=%2
del "%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt"
del "%TEMP%\selectortemp2.txt"
for /r %loopnum% %%i in (\*.*) do echo %%~ni%%~xi>>"%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt"

echo %loopnum%
pause

set count=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt) do set /a count+=1

set /a count2=1
:looping

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (%config%) do (if %%a==url set url=%%b)

set /p firstline=<"%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt"

del "%url%\%firstline%"

echo "%firstline%"
pause

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt) do echo %%A>>"%TEMP%\selectortemp2.txt"
del "%TEMP%\selectortemp.txt"
rename "%TEMP%\selectortemp2.txt" "selectortemp.txt"

if %count2%==%count% goto endlooping
set /a count2+=1
goto looping
:endlooping
```

At first, I call it by this:

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,3) do (call b.bat %%i C:\testing)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loses its variables"? Please describe your problem a bit more. (Use the edit button to add more info to your post. Also next time, please use the `{}` code button for your code/batch files.)

Comment: sry... I find that .bat wouldnt lose it actually. I mean it wouldnt become a emty variable. However, its because my looping is poor so poor that the .bat crashes. I will use {} next time. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific with your question.
I asume that you mean that your variables lose their content in the for loops.

You need to write !a! instead of %a%. But you can't do this with the variable used in the for loop. !!a is not possible.

Be sure to enable delayed expansion.

Here's some information about enabledelayedexpansion: [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)